# Possible to get the git branch name in a dockerfile?

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile

Not sure if this is even possible. But what I want is to change this line of code inside the dockerfile

```
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --env=prod
```

to

```
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --env=test
```

Or better how do I make something like this work in gitbal-ci.yml file:

```
# Production build
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t $CONTAINER_ENV_IMAGE .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_ENV_IMAGE
  args:
    - env=prod
  only:
    - master

# Test build
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t $CONTAINER_ENV_IMAGE .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_ENV_IMAGE
  args:
    - env=test
  except:
    - master
```

but only if the git branch name is test. I am using gitlab to build the images.

I need this in order to change the api url environment variable in angular.
Is this possible or are there any better ways perhaps?

Comment: This is a pretty normal thing to want to do.  Is this something you are doing in a CI/CD environment?

Comment: Yes so this has to happen before the building process. Right now I have to change the dockerfile everytime I switch from production to test or vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder) supports [build arguments](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact) and [environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement). So its possible to specify which branch to use and then decide command based upon the branch. For example, to pass build args use docker build--build-arg =. Then you can set a variable based upon the git_branch variable that decides the env to use.

```
FROM busybox
ARG git_branch
RUN echo “Building $git_branch”
```

Comment: I have edited the post can you look again at the part with the gitlab-ci.yml file. I am not sure how to pass the env depending on which branch iam in inside the yml file.

Comment: Simply change the script gitlab.yml script like this:


      script:
           - docker build --pull -t $CONTAINER_ENV_IMAGE --build-arg env_to_use=test .

And in the docker file use: 
...
ARG git_branch
....
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --env=$env_to_use

Comment: You mean like this?

gitlab-ci.yml:
script: - docker build --pull -t $CONTAINER_ENV_IMAGE --build-arg BUILDENV=test

Dockerfile:
ARG BUILDENV
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --env=$BUILDENV

Comment: Yes, that should do it. I haven't write the code though.

Answer (score 2):

In docker 1.9 a step along the way would be to use a build argument to differentiate between the prod and dev environments using a build argument:

```
docker build --build-arg local_config=test
```

And in the docker file:

```
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --env=$local_config
```