# How to use BRANCH_NAME with cloudbuild.yaml and Dockerfile in Google Cloud Build

Tags: dockerfile, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I have been using Dockerfile and cloudbuild.yaml to build images succesfully,

But now I need to have the BRANCH_NAME value inside the Dockerfile, and since this requirement showed up, my docker builds have started failing.

Here below is my cloudbuild.yaml file :

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  env:
    - '$BRANCH_NAME=${_$BRANCH_NAME}'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'docker pull gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/github.com/videoo-io/videoo-render-$BRANCH_NAME:latest || exit 0']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  env:
    - '$BRANCH_NAME=${_$BRANCH_NAME}'
  args: [
            'build',
            "--build-arg=ENV=$_BRANCH_NAME",
            '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/github.com/videoo-io/videoo-render-$BRANCH_NAME:latest',
            '--cache-from', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/github.com/videoo-io/videoo-render-$BRANCH_NAME:latest',
            '.'
        ]
substitutions:
  _BRANCH_NAME: $BRANCH_NAME
options:
  dynamic_substitutions: true
images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/github.com/videoo-io/videoo-render-$BRANCH_NAME:latest']
timeout: 7200s
```

And below is my Dockerfile :

```
ARG  BRANCH_NAME=$_BRANCH_NAME

FROM --platform=amd64 gcr.io/videoo7/github.com/videoo-io/videoo-render-${BRANCH_NAME}:latest

EXPOSE 80
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN cd /app && cmake . && make

# Define default command.
RUN chmod +x /app/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

I cannot get BRANCH_NAME correctly as a substitute variable as suggested here : [Google Cloud Build Substitute Variables Link](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#yaml)

This is the failing build logs :

```
Step #0: a561219ed4f5: Pull complete
Step #0: Digest: sha256:09a3f79713e906ff0640bac04c9cb74523ee33e930afe8683f15f2cd5904fbc1
Step #0: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/videoo7/github.com/videoo-io/videoo-render-main:latest
Step #0: gcr.io/videoo7/github.com/videoo-io/videoo-render-main:latest
Finished Step #0
Starting Step #1
Step #1: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Step #1: Sending build context to Docker daemon  196.9MB

Step #1: Step 1/8 : ARG  BRANCH_NAME=$_BRANCH_NAME
Step #1: Step 2/8 : FROM --platform=amd64 gcr.io/videoo7/github.com/videoo-io/videoo-render-${BRANCH_NAME}:latest
Step #1: invalid reference format
Finished Step #1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Here is my google cloud build trigger setup :

[image: BRANCH_NAME]

What shall I do in order to have BRANCH_NAME value inside the Dockerfile ?

Comment: In your Dockerfile can you try `ARG BRANCH_NAME` instead of `ARG BRANCH_NAME=$_BRANCH_NAME`

Comment: Now I get this : 
Step #1: Step 1/8 : ARG BRANCH_NAME
Step #1: Step 2/8 : FROM --platform=amd64 ${BRANCH_NAME}
Step #1: base name (${BRANCH_NAME}) should not be blank
Finished Step #1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1

Comment: In the `env` section both steps can you set `BRANCH_NAME=$BRANCH_NAME`  as in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#yaml) that you shared

Comment: I have tried setting BRANCH_NAME as suggested : 

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [
            'build',
            '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/github.com/videoo-io/videoo-render-$BRANCH_NAME:latest',
            '--cache-from', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/github.com/videoo-io/videoo-render-$BRANCH_NAME:latest',
            '.'
        ]
  env:
  - 'BRANCH_NAME=$BRANCH_NAME'

Step #1: Step 1/8 : ARG BRANCH_NAME
Step #1: Step 2/8 : FROM --platform=amd64 ${BRANCH_NAME}
Step #1: base name (${BRANCH_NAME}) should not be blank

Still no luck

Comment: I am building through Google Cloud Build trigger, where can I execute this command : gcloud builds submit --config=cloudbuild.yaml \ 
    --substitutions=TAG_NAME="test" as suggested by this document https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#yaml

Comment: Why there is not Dockerfile example in here https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#yaml

Comment: Use substitutions in your build config file to substitute specific variables at build time Also have a look at this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58886293/getting-current-branch-and-commit-hash-in-github-action), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49134348/possible-to-get-the-git-branch-name-in-a-dockerfile)&[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58939845/get-branch-name-in-dockerfile)